# Create action for a button inside collection view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I have created a UICollection View inside a storyboard, I have created a button inside the cell, whenever I tap on the button I should filter the data as per my condition, so each and every buttons inside the cell will have different conditions, can anyone help me out with this issue ?? Iam using xcode 9 and swift 4.

Comment: Add your current code please

Answer (score 2):

Use `addTarget` of your button inside `cellForItemAt:indexPath` datasource and add a `selector` where action of the button will be defined. Add this button's tag, (add it same as your `indexPath.row`, that you can use to differentiate your button from collectionview)

```
cell.yourButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
cell.yourButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

Now add the action of that button and inside that perform any action you need.

```
@IBAction func yourButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //perform action
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom UICollectionViewCell type. Wire up an IBAction to the cell.

Create a protocol that lets the cell notify the collection view that the user tapped a button. Have the action pass the tap to the delegate.

In your `cellForItemAt()` method, set the view controller as the delegate.

Now in your view controller handle the tap as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Objective c

Add below code at cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
cell.btnOk.tag = indexPath.row ;
[cell.btnOk addTarget:self action:@selector(OkBtnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside] ;
```

Than add the action of that button

```
-(IBAction)OkBtnAction:(id)sender
{
    UIButton* btn=(UIButton*)sender;
    NSLog(@"row: %ld",(long)btn.tag);

}
```